# Steps in proof of Proposition 2.4.17 in Liu

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am going through the proof of Proposition 4.17 in Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves:

[image]

**First question (SOLVED):**

I can't verify why $V(f\vert_U)$ contains $W\cap U$. If we write $\phi:W\cong\operatorname{Spec}A$ and $\psi:U\cong\operatorname{Spec}B$, then formally $W=V(f\vert_W)$ means that
$$
\phi(W)=V({\phi^\#}^{-1}f\vert_W)=V(\mathfrak p).
$$
where for notational convenience $a={\phi^\#}^{-1}f\vert_W$. And $W\cap U\subset V(f\vert_U)$ means that
$$
\psi(W\cap U)=\psi(W)\cap\operatorname{Spec}B=V({\psi^\#}^{-1}f\vert_V)=V(b)
$$
with $b={\psi^\#}^{-1}f\vert_V$. So let $x\in W$. We need to show that $b\in\psi(x)$. We know that
$$
a\in\phi(x).
$$

*Attempt (SOLVED):*

Let's say for notational convenience that $W=\operatorname{Spec}A$ (equality as opposed to an isomorphism). We still work with an explicit isomorphism $\psi:U\cong\operatorname{Spec}(B)$. So we want to show that
$$
\psi(\psi^{-1}(U)\cap W)=V(b)
$$
where $b=(\psi^{-1})^\#f\vert_W$. Let $x\in \psi^{-1}(U)\cap W$. Then $x$ is given by a prime $\mathfrak p$ of $A$, and write $f\vert_W=a\in A$. Then we know that $a\in\mathfrak p$.  Write $\mathfrak q=\psi(\mathfrak p)$. Choose some $g\in A$ such that
$$
\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec}(A_g)\subset \psi^{-1}(U)\cap W.
$$
Note that we have a sheaf map
$$
\Psi=\psi\vert_{\operatorname{Spec}(A_g)}:\operatorname{Spec} A_g\to\psi(\operatorname{Spec}A_g)\subset\operatorname{Spec}B,
$$
which corresponds to a map of rings
$$
G:B\to A_g,
$$
i.e., $\Psi=\operatorname{Spec}(G)$. So we have
$$
G^{-1}(\mathfrak p)=\mathfrak q.
$$
To conclude that $b\in\mathfrak q$, I would need that $G(b)=a$. This is true, if we remember that $b=(\psi^{-1})^\# f\vert_U$ and $a=f\vert_W$ and that $G$ corresponds to $\psi^\#$ (along with restriction). More precisely, we have
$$
a/1\in A_g=\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}A}(\operatorname{Spec}A_g),
$$
and
$$
G:\sigma\mapsto \sigma\vert_{\psi(\operatorname{Spec}A_g)}\mapsto \psi^\#\sigma\vert_{\psi(\operatorname{Spec}A_g)}.
$$
so recalling the definition of $b$, we get indeed
$$
G:b\mapsto f\vert_{\operatorname{Spec}A_g}=a/1\in A_g.
$$
It's clear to me how to adapt this proof for the 'general' case where we have an isomorphism $\phi:U\cong\operatorname{Spec}A$ (instead of equality), which I won't write down.

**Second question (SOLVED):**

How can I show that $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ would be generic points of $U_1\cap U_2$?

*Attempt: (SOLVED)*

Let $Z_i=\overline{\{\xi_i\}}$. I know that $U_1\cap U_2$ is irreducible, and hence contains a generic point $\xi$ (since $U$ is a scheme), i.e.
$$
\operatorname{Cl}_{U_1\cap U_2}(\xi)=U_1\cap U_2.
$$
It follows that
$$
\operatorname{Cl}_{U_1}(\{\xi\})=\operatorname{Cl}_{U_1}\operatorname{Cl}_{U_1\cap U_2}(\{\xi\})=\operatorname{Cl}_{U_1}(U_1\cap U_2)=U_1,
$$
where in the last step I used that $U_1\cap U_2$ is dense in $U_1$ (which follows from irreducibility of $U_1$). Therefore
$$
\operatorname{Cl}_{Z_1\cap U_1}(\{\xi\})=\operatorname{Cl}_{U_1}(\{\xi\})\cap U_1\cap Z_1=U_1\cap Z_1.
$$
Now using that $U_1\cap Z_1$ is dense in $Z_1$ (by irreducibility of $Z_1$), we conclude that
$$
\operatorname{Cl}_{Z_1}(\{\xi_i\})=\operatorname{Cl}_{Z_1}(\operatorname{Cl}_{Z_1\cap U_1}(\{\xi\}))=Z_1.
$$
and hence $\xi=\xi_1$ by uniqueness of the generic point. The case for $Z_2$ is similar.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is the spectrum of an integral domain, $\xi$ is the generic point of $X\iff \{\xi\} = \cap_{U: \text{ non-empty open subset of }X }U$. Using this, $\{\xi_1\}=\cap_{\emptyset \neq U \subset U_1\cap U_2}U=\{\xi_2\}$ if $U_1 \cap U_2 \neq \emptyset.$

Comment: I know that if $\xi$ is generic in $X$, then $\xi\in V$ for any non-empty open $ V$. My problem is that $\xi_i$ is just generic in the sense that $\overline{\xi_i}=Z_i$ is an irreducible component. I suppose I can show then that $\{\xi_i\}=\bigcap_{U\text{ open}:U\cap Z\neq\emptyset}(U\cap Z_i)$, but then it seems I need to show that for any open $U\subset U_1\cap U_2$, we have $U\cap Z_i\neq \emptyset$. So could you clarify why $U_1\cap U_2\cap Z_1\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: Liu’s definition of a generic point states that if $\xi_1\in U_1$ is a generic point of $X$, it is also a (the) generic point of $U_1$. In particular, $U_1\cap Z_1 =$ the closure of $\{\xi_1\}$ in $U_1$ = $U_1$ and $U_1\cap U_2\cap Z_1=U_1\cap U_2\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: I'm not sure about $U_1\cap U_2\cap Z_1=U_1\cap U_2$ (the latter is open while the former isn't necessarily), but it doesn't matter, because I have arrived at an argument via another route.